Citation for webpage's heading-less introductory section?
Many webpages have an initial introductory section. Unlike later sections, this generally does not have a heading. For a good example, see here.
From what I've been able to find, APA-7 says to use the format (Section name section) format when citing webpages.* How do you use this with an untitled introductory section? Do you just use the article's title?
You can also use paragraph numbers or a combination of sections and paragraphs, but generally if you're using section or section-paragraph, the webpage is too long to get away with just paragraphs—hence my question.

Pleas explain that much more clearly. I followed your link and it led to a page which in no way matched your description… unless you're using a special definition of headings, or sections, or both.

@RobbieGoodwin The page I provided has an introductory section ("Why should Christian's care about the arts? ... Engage in these questions with artists Marilynne Robinson, Seth Avett, Anne Lamott and Elizabeth Alexander; as well as theologians and thinkers Jeremy S. Begbie, Richard B. Hays, Samuel Wells, Andy Crouch and Ellen F. Davis."), but no section header for that section.

Sorry and no, absolutely not. The link you provided does include much content under 'Why should Christian's care about the arts?' but that is only after inches of the headings and introductions you deny.

Most style guides don't require giving a section or paragraph number for online sources. If something is unambiguously an introduction you could cite it as Introduction (APA doesn't need quotes around chapter names or article titles).

I don't see your problem. The rule says to use either a heading or section name or a paragraph number or both. Since the introductory section in your example has no heading or section name, only the option to give a paragraph number remains. So give a paragraph number.

The problem is that there are headings elsewhere, and with longer websites I find it impractical to use paragraphs ("(para. 420)" vs. "(Fizz Buzz section).")

@InHocSigno Your question says that you want to cite from the beginning of the text. You won't have to count to more than 20 or so. For quotations from lower on the webpage you can use section names (plus paragraph numbers, if you want, counted within that section, not from the top of the webpage). I don't see the problem.
